# How to prevent Jmeter from adding the default content type if left blank?

Tags: jmeter

I have to perform functional testing for few Api's, where if the content type is left blank then the application should mention "Content-Type is invalid".
But in Jmeter if i sent "Content type = "(blank) in header manager ,Jmeter is adding the content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Please help me how to prevent Jmeter from adding the default content type, if left blank?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should provide correct Content-Type header which can be something like:

- `application/json` for [REST](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)
- `text/xml; charset="utf-8"` for [SOAP](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/)

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for a little bit more detailed information on the domain

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can provide more details about your test plan and the way how you defined the content-type header. Is it a POST request and if yes, what's the content you send in body?

Did a quick test - Jmeter successfully sends blank Content-Type header, here is a screenshot:

[image]